# Make an ip based virtual host only respond to a single host name

Tags: apache-2.2, hosts, virtualization

Is it possible to make an apache ip based virutal host only respond to a specific host name?

I have a rouge domain name pointing to my server. I know I could redirect it or throw up a 401, but would just rather the server not even respond to a request with this hostname.

Answer (score 4):

Any request with a `Host` header that does not match the `ServerName` in any `<VirtualHost>` section falls through to the "main" server configuration. As such here is no way to outright prevent a connection, but you can "short circuit" the request by sending back a blank response, or by pointing `DocumentRoot` somewhere that doesn't exist.

Comment: Or send back a 404 following the advice given here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/231438/how-do-i-configure-the-default-virtual-host-return-a-404-header-in-apache