# How do I configure the default virtual host return a 404 header in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I know that similar questions have been asked, but the available answers are not very clear, so please bear with me.

After setting up a few `<VirtualHost>`s in apache, I'd like to configure the `_default`_ ServerName so that it returns the 404 message. I.e., unless some explicitly available domain is specified in the Host http header, return 404. (Ideally something more direct than pointing to a now-nonexistent directory.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Did you try:

```
Redirect 404 /
ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
```

in the default VirtualHost?

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Since it's clear my low level of expertise, I might add for my fellow newbies that the default server should appear first. (This took me a while to figure out!)

Comment: NOTE that if the `ErrorDocument` points to a file or url inside that vhost, it will also return a 404, thus generating an internal server error.

Comment: This answer would work for sites where all the vhosts are contained in a single file (Eugene Fidelin's answer is more complete). When using separate .conf files for each site with a2ensite, I could not figure out how to load the default (404) configuration first.

Comment: `Redirect 404 /` is enough to show the default Apache "Not Found" page and it also works inside a specific virtualhost (there can be cases when you'd like to return 404 for an entire site to make it disappear from Google SERPs)

Comment: For those having the same issue as Andrez Swift: vhost configuration files are including in alphanumerical order, which makes it best practice to prefix the files with their numerical priority, allowing you to easily rearrange them. Use 000-default.conf for your "catch-all" configuration and for example 010-mysite.conf for specific vhosts. And one "gotcha" for me is that even just specifying the IP in the <VirtualHost ...> made it match that vhost over the default (even tho ServerName did not match)... More on vhost matching: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is example of 000-default.conf that will return 404 error if server name is not configured for Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I can confirm that the second part works when all the vhosts are configured in a single file (I put it first).

Comment: It might better to use 503 (Service Unavailable) instead of 404, but I doubt in practice it makes much difference, monitoring tools will usually alert for any non-200 codes.

Comment: It's working perfectly for http but not for https when I do with port 443. Do you have any idea about that?