# Redirect from https-URL request to http-server IP is not working

Tags: debian, ssl-certificate, apache2

In the second call of my Apache 2.4 server config-vhost file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx
    ServerName 51.89.98.21
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://51.89.98.21$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://51.89.98.21/ [R=permanent,END,QSA]            
</VirtualHost>
```

The third config-vhost is this one (section):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin  xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx
   ServerName   www.developmentscout.com
   ServerAlias  developmentscout.com   
   UseCanonicalName Off
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/developmentscout.com/htdocs"
   
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\.well\-known [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^developmentscout.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.developmentscout.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/developmentscout.com-0002/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/developmentscout.com-0002/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/developmentscout.com-0002/chain.pem
...
```

The link from https://51.89.98.21/industrie/automatisierung/ipc/11315-edge-computing
should redirected to http://51.89.98.21 BUT instead I have a redirection to: http://51.89.98.21/industrie/automatisierung/ipc/11315-edge-computing, which shows me the content of the "real" page.

The second vhost is never reached because in the log I have this:

[Tue Oct 24 18:44:23.156932 2023] [ssl:debug] [pid 8958:tid 140379014039296] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 98.58.102.21:64004] AH02034: Subsequent (No.3) HTTPS request received for child 22272 (server [www.developmentscout.com:443](http://www.developmentscout.com:443)), referer: https://51.89.98.21/industrie/automatisierung/ipc/11315-edge-computing

Obviously the https request goes to the wrong URL which calls a SSL certificate, which is wrong, then used a http connection and shows the content.

I have tried to create a SSL certificate with Letsencrypt, but that's not possible for an IP.
So any suggestions how to solve this, would be great.

**UPDATE**:
In the meantime I have created a self-signed certificate for 51.89.98.21. The (second after the default) vhost is:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin struck.jens@gmail.com
        ServerName 51.89.98.21
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ca-certificates/key.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^51.89.98.21/$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://51.89.98.21/ [END,QSA,R=permanent]
        DocumentRoot /var/www/server3           
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I call this URL: https://51.89.98.21/branche/automobil/11819-e-auto-laden-ladestecker-ladekabel
I got a Not Found 404.

Comment: Why are you doing this with an IP instead of a domain which would be the easiest and best way to do it?

Comment: Because I have found thousands of weird backlinks with Ahrefs beginning all with: https://51.89.98.21 and I'd like to eliminate them from the web and Ahrefs.

Comment: `When I call this URL` why do you call the URLs via the IP in the first place? If you don't want content to be reachable via IP just configure the VirtualHost to [not return any content at all](https://serverfault.com/questions/231438/how-do-i-configure-the-default-virtual-host-return-a-404-header-in-apache) and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. Yep this work also. Sometimes I like it a bit more complicated ;-)
BTW: nice description for changing a Synology disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AI told me, that the condition

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^51.89.98.21/$ [NC]

will never be true because %{HTTP_HOST} only contains the domain name (or IP in this case) without the trailing slash.

So the modification should be:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$